# Calling nested JavaScript function through HTML (simple)

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is a duplicate topic, but this topic is different because i use very simple examples. I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
(function myfunction($){
    function a(){
        alert("A section"); 
    }
    function b(){
        alert("B section")
    }
})();
```

I want to create a HTML button which calls function A, and function B. How can i do that?

Comment: You cannot access those functions from outside the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them global by declaring the names outside the closure, then assign them within the closure.

```
var a, b;
(function myfunction($){
    a = function() {
        alert("A section"); 
    }
    b = function() {
        alert("B section")
    }
})();
```

You can reduce the pollution of the global namespace by wrapping them in an object:

```
var myfuns = (function myfunction($) {
                 return { a: function() {alert("A section");},
                          b: function() {alert("B section");}
                        };
              })();
```

Then call `myfuns.a` and `myfuns.b`.

Comment: It would be nice to other posters if you accepted answers in your old questions, too.

Comment: I'll do it. btw, I new to this site.

Comment: Huh? You've been here for a year and a half!

Comment: Yes, but i didn't understood the potential of stackoverflow. I didn't took stackoverflow seriously, until now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object that has these function and call your functions like below :

```
myFunctions = {

  a : function(){ alert("A section"); },
  b : function(){ alert("B section"); }

}
```

and then call them like below :

```
myFunctions.a();
myFunctions.b();
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tEVs/) to check it.

**UPDATE:**

As answer to your comment, this is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tEVs/1/) to show you how it works from HTML.

Comment: This method can't call myFunctions.a(); and myFunctions.b(); through a HTML button.

Comment: Yes you can, if you are including your javascript in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Assign function to global variables in closure is one way. Other way to do it is following.

```
(function myfunction($){
    $("#button1").click(function {
        alert("A section"); 
    });
    $("#button2").click(function {
        alert("B section"); 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This doesn't spoil your global scope. And binds on click event for your buttons.

When not using jQuery

```
(function myfunction($){
    var button1 = getElementById("idOfButton1");
    button1.onclick = function {
        alert("A section"); 
    };
    var button2 = getElementById("idOfButton2");
    button1.onclick = function {
        alert("B section"); 
    };
})();
```

Comment: When did he say he's using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable first, and then expose it to global context:

```
(function myfunction($){
    var global = {
        a: function(){
            alert("A section");
        },
        b: function(){
            alert("B section")
        }
    };

    window.global = global;
})();
global.a();
global.b();
```

Comment: @Mathletics Would you mind telling me if I mislead something?

Comment: Well you didn't use any jQuery, so I don't know what that statement is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Mathletics Thanks for telling me. I don't mean I use jQuery code here. In jQuery, we can find such code: "window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;", so I use the similar syntax in the answer. I've deleted the ambiguous words.